# Replicate table data within same table

Tags: sql-server

This is bit hard to explain but I am replicating(copying) the data associated to an id.  I want to copy the data sequence from Table 1 to Table 2. I can do this manually but I have move than 100 different id which I have to update the data. Is there any way through which I can copy the data faster. I just have to change the id rest should be same.

Example:

Data 1 within Table 1

```
        +-------------+---------------+----------+----------------------------------+
        + item_number +  order_number +    id    +            text                  +
        +-------------+---------------+----------+----------------------------------+
        +     1       +      1        +   285    +          Question 1              +
        +-------------+---------------+----------+----------------------------------+
        +     1       +      2        +   285    +          Question 2              +
        +-------------+---------------+----------+----------------------------------+
        +     1       +      1        +   285    +          Question 3              +
        +-------------+---------------+----------+----------------------------------+
        +     1       +      1        +   285    +          Question 4              +
        +-------------+---------------+----------+----------------------------------+
        +     2       +      1        +   285    +          Question 5              +
        +-------------+---------------+----------+----------------------------------+
        +     2       +      1        +   285    +          Question 6              +
        +-------------+---------------+----------+----------------------------------+
        +     3       +      1        +   285    +          Question 7              + 
        +-------------+---------------+----------+----------------------------------+
        +     4       +      1        +   285    +          Question 8              +
        +-------------+---------------+----------+----------------------------------+
        +     4       +      1        +   285    +          Question 9              +
        +-------------+---------------+----------+----------------------------------+
```

Data 2 within Table 1

```
    +-------------+---------------+----------+----------------------------------+
    + item_number +  order_number +    id    +            text                  +
    +-------------+---------------+----------+----------------------------------+
    +     1       +      1        +   356    +          Question 1              +
    +-------------+---------------+----------+----------------------------------+
    +     1       +      2        +   356    +          Question 2              +
    +-------------+---------------+----------+----------------------------------+
    +     1       +      1        +   356    +          Question 3              +
    +-------------+---------------+----------+----------------------------------+
    +     1       +      1        +   356    +          Question 4              +
    +-------------+---------------+----------+----------------------------------+
    +     2       +      1        +   356    +          Question 5              +
    +-------------+---------------+----------+----------------------------------+
    +     2       +      1        +   356    +          Question 6              +
    +-------------+---------------+----------+----------------------------------+
    +     2       +      1        +   356    +          Question 7              + 
    +-------------+---------------+----------+----------------------------------+
    +     3       +      1        +   356    +          Question 8              +
    +-------------+---------------+----------+----------------------------------+
```

**Just FYI: I just have copy data with same table. Means its like an Update statement not Insert Statement**

Comment: So what exactly is the desired result? Just to add the rows from table1 to table2?

Comment: @Mureinik Just updating item_number, page_number and text columns based on the sequence which is changed in Data 1.

Comment: What's the logic to update item_number? What constitutes the ID change? what happened to item_number 4? What's the logic to determine when and what items get updated? what is the "sequence" and what determines it?

Comment: Can you explain the logic for item_number?

Comment: Item_number works like page number. So when a new question is added to any of the page item number and order_number gets changes as you can see in Data 1.

Answer (score 0):

Does this statement working for you?

```
INSERT INTO table2
 SELECT * FROM table1;
```

Comment: I have reedit my decription I am updating my data within same table.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to copy the data with a conditional update on the ID field. You can do that with a `CASE`

```
SELECT 
item_number,
order_number,
case
  when id = 285 then 356
  --add other id changes
end as [id],
[text]
INTO Table2
FROM Table1
```

Comment: I have reedit my decription I am updating my data within same table.